# 2.93 - How to Align a diagonal UV seam for a repeating Texture?

Tags: uv-image-editor

Practicing UV today ran into this issue. Trying to make this roof texture match exactly on the corners as shown in the image on right. How to Align this diagonal UV seam for a repeating Texture? The roof texture is a seamless repeating 2k image. Also, In the UV editor, When a single edge is selected there is this strange gradient. Where is the setting to turn that off?
[image: uv seam]

[image: selected face]

Answer (score 1):

You can do an *Unwrap > Project from View* from the top view, then, in the *UV Editor*, rotate the triangular part, move it, scale a bit:

[image]

you should be able to make the tiles match:

[image]